# Scroll the web page horizontally when the small screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

When the screen is small on the screen would scroll horizontally

When the screen is small to come down menus

Comment: add `overflow-y: scroll` to body or page container. And for your information, you have to post your code when asking

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Could you clarify it?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
  <style> 
   div {
     overflow-x: scroll;
   }
   </style>
```